# Brass & Marble Chinese Bring Money Tea Pot (Characters identified: 大明宣德)

Tags: character-identification, seal

[image]Hello,
What do the Chinese makers mark tell?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The characters are

> 大朙宣德
>
> Emperor [Xuāndé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xuande_Emperor) of the [Míng Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ming_dynasty)